# Difference between the AND statement in an Inner Join or in a WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

Hello guys I have a specific question about the AND clause in SQL.

The two following SQL statements provide the same output:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 t1 INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id AND t2.id = 0


SELECT * FROM Table1 t1 INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id WHERE t2.id = 0
```

Notice the difference at the end of the query. In the first one, I use the AND clause (without using the WHERE clause before). In the second one, I use a WHERE to specify my id.

1. Is the first syntax correct?
2. If yes, is the first one better in terms of performance (not using WHERE clause for filtering after)?
3. Should I expect different outputs with different queries?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can take a look at the query plan generated by the database, and see if they are different. With a MySQL database you can do that with the EXPLAIN statement, for other databases there probably is something similar.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, no, and no.

To be specific:

1. Yes, the syntax is correct.  Conceptually, the first query creates an inner join between `t1` and `t2` with the join condition `t1.id = t2.id AND t2.id = 0`, while the second creates an inner join on `t1.id = t2.id` and then filters the result using the condition `t2.id = 0`.

   However, no SQL engine I know of would actually execute either query like that.  Rather, in both cases, the engine will optimize both of them to something like `t1.id = 0 AND t2.id = 0` and then do two single-row lookups.
2. No, pretty much any reasonable SQL engine should treat these two queries as effectively identical.
3. No, see above.

By the way, the following ways to write the same query are also valid:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 t1 INNER JOIN Table2 t2 WHERE t1.id = t2.id AND t2.id = 0

SELECT * FROM Table1 t1, Table2 t2 WHERE t1.id = t2.id AND t2.id = 0
```

Comment: Nice answer.  With INNER JOIN, things are pretty straight-forward.  With an OUTER JOIN and appropriately complex conditions, it can make a difference whether the filtering operation is in the JOIN or in the (main query's) WHERE clause.

Comment: Thx for main answer. And yes I noticed this Jonathan in the case of the outer joins. Thanks for your input! Edit: Yes for the second way Ilmary but I'd rather stick with the ANSI syntax.

Comment: I think Ilmari Karonen already gave an excellent answer. Use the INNER JOIN ON part to define the Join between the tables (like t1.id = t2.id) and use the WHERE part for the business rules, like where t2.amount = 0. There is no speed penalty for that, only clearer code for the human reader.

Comment: And also `SELECT * FROM Table1 t1, Table2 t2 WHERE t1.id = 0 AND t2.id = 0`

Comment: @Ilmari Karonen: The `Table1 t1 INNER JOIN Table2 t2 WHERE ...` is valid only in MySQL. If you made that `CROSS JOIN`, yes, it would be valid.